# How to create conditional clause if column in dataframe is empty?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
fname                   lname
joe                      smith
john smith      
jane@jane.com            
jacky /jax               jack
a@a.com                  non
john (jack)              smith
Bob J. Smith
```

I want to create logic that says that if `lname` is empty, and if there are two `OR` three strings in `fname` seperate the second string `OR` third string and push it into `lname` column. If email address in `fname` leave as is, and if slashes or parenthesis in the `fname` column and no value in `lname` leave as is.

new df:

```
fname                   lname
    joe                      smith
    john                     smith
    jane@jane.com            
    jacky /jax               jack
    a@a.com                  non
    john (jack)              smith
    Bob J.                   smith
```

Code so far to seperate two strings:

```
df[['lname']] = df['name'].loc[df['fname'].str.split().str.len() == 2].str.split(expand=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following sample dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'fname': ['joe', 'john smith', 'jane@jane.com', 'jacky /jax', 'a@a.com', 'john (jack)', 'Bob J. Smith'],
     'lname': ['smith', '', '', 'jack', 'non', 'smith', '']})
```

You can use `np.where()`:

```
conditions = (df['lname']=='') & (df['fname'].str.split().str.len()>1)

df['lname'] = np.where(conditions, df['fname'].str.split().str[-1].str.lower(), df['lname'])
```

Yields:

```
           fname  lname
0            joe  smith
1     john smith  smith
2  jane@jane.com       
3     jacky /jax   jack
4        a@a.com    non
5    john (jack)  smith
6   Bob J. Smith  smith
```

To remove the last string from the `fname` column of the rows that had their `lname` column populated:

```
df['fname'] = np.where(conditions, df['fname'].str.split().str[:-1].str.join(' '), df['fname'])
```

Yields:

```
           fname  lname
0            joe  smith
1           john  smith
2  jane@jane.com       
3     jacky /jax   jack
4        a@a.com    non
5    john (jack)  smith
6         Bob J.  smith
```

Comment: thank you for the response. Your code is working but not producing the desired results. The conditions variable is boolean values that are all False. not sure what to do.

Comment: Are you sure that your blank values are empty strings? I've updated my answer with the sample dataframe I used.

Comment: The code is working now,the issue was the blank values were not empty strings, but it is not deleting the second string from the `fname` column just duplicating into 'lname'

Comment: Woops, missed that part of your question. I've updated my answer to account for that now.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have a dataframe with columns `fname` and `lname`. If so then you can modify empty rows in column `lname` with:

```
condition = (df.loc[:, 'lname'] == '') & (df.loc[:, 'fname'].str.contains(' '))
df.loc[condition, 'lname'] = df.loc[condition, 'fname'].str.split().str[-1]
```

The code works for the sample data you have provided in the question but should be improved to be used in more general case.

To modify column `fname` you may use:

```
df.loc[condition, 'fname'] = df.loc[condition, 'fname'].str.split().str[:-1].str.join(sep=' ')
```

Comment: thank you for the response. Your code is working but not producing the results. No error given. Pretty much I want to scan `fname` column for names with two strings and take the second string pushing it into `lname`

Comment: Condition creates a list of boolean values all false